# Decoding a string URL column in PySpark

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, urllib, apache-spark-sql

I am using Python 2.7 and Spark 2.2.0. I have created a data frame in PySpark which has a string column type and contains URLs.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('example.com?title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0',)], ['url'])
df.show(1, False)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|url                                                                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|example.com?title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To decode all the URLs in the column I tried to use urllib. I created a `udf`. I'm using it like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
decode_url = udf(lambda val: (urllib.unquote(val).decode('utf8'), StringType()))
```

After applying a `udf` over my column I was expecting this :

```
+---------------------------------+
|url                              |
+---------------------------------+
|example.com?title=правовая+защита|
+---------------------------------+
```

But I got an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-33: ordinal not in range(128)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I take out some url from the column and try to decode it separately, it's working fine:

```
import urllib 
url='example.com?title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0'
print urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
example.com?title=правовая+защита
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like under the hood there is some strange encoding going on. Why don't you explicitly encode it yourself?

```
>>> decode_udf= udf(lambda val: urllib.unquote(val.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'), StringType())
>>> df.withColumn('decoded_url', decode_udf('url')).show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|url                                                                                                    |decoded_url                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|example.com?title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0|example.com?title=правовая+защита|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------+
``
```

Answer (score 3):

*If you want to do this in spark sql you can do like this:*

**Note : encoded field name is dctr**

**Input:** `im_segments%3Debejz4gv%2Ck1GmZLwg%2C8zY92P4g%2Cka6ee4eb%2CgPKlZXXb%2CqkVvpGk9%2Cky1ee4Dk%2CgvqKoW0b%2CgO5l6Zrk%2CgO5lGpdk%2CxkD6AYgm%2CgO5rENWk%2Cg7VrxvDb`

**Expected output:** `im_segments=ebejz4gv,k1GmZLwg,8zY92P4g,ka6ee4eb,gPKlZXXb,qkVvpGk9,ky1ee4Dk,gvqKoW0b,gO5l6Zrk,gO5lGpdk,xkD6AYgm,gO5rENWk,g7VrxvDb`

**Answer:**

```
select distinct reflect('java.net.URLDecoder','decode', dctr , 'utf-8') as dctr from table
```

Comment: Nice! This works great in pyspark too: `.withColumn('page', F.expr("reflect('java.net.URLDecoder','decode', uri, 'utf-8')"))`

Answer (score 0):

**Spark 3.5+**

```py
F.url_decode('url')
```

**Spark 3.4+**

```py
F.expr("url_decode(url)")
```

---

Examples:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('url', F.url_decode('url')).show(1, 0)
# +---------------------------------+
# |url                              |
# +---------------------------------+
# |example.com?title=правовая защита|
# +---------------------------------+

df.withColumn('url', F.expr("url_decode(url)")).show(1, 0)
# +---------------------------------+
# |url                              |
# +---------------------------------+
# |example.com?title=правовая защита|
# +---------------------------------+
```